# Problems with Python & Pandas: Adding calculated column to dataframe that includes data from a function provides error

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I am trying to add a calculated column: "NetEarnings" to my DataFram "Wages".  The "NetEarnings" column subtracting Tax from AnnualIncome; tax is drawing from a function I created to calculate taxes.  It will not let me add this new column due to an error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'"

I have tried mostly everything, unsure if I made a dumb mistake somewhere.  Thanks for your help!

Code:

```
def Tax(AnnualIncome):
    if (0 < AnnualIncome) & (AnnualIncome <= 21450):
        return (.15 * AnnualIncome)
    elif (21450 < AnnualIncome) & (AnnualIncome <= 51900):
        return (3215.5 + ((AnnualIncome - 21450) * .28))
    else: 
        return (11,743.5 + ((AnnualIncome - 51900) * .31))

wages['Tax'] = wages['AnnualIncome'].apply(Tax)

# Problem line
wages['NetEarning'] = wages['AnnualIncome'] - wages['Tax']
```

[image]

Error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Ente answer,

I suggest to use np.where instead of apply. Apply is faster than a for loop, but much slower than apply.

A possible solution would be:

```
np.where(df['AnnualIncome'] <= 21450, (.15 *df['AnnualIncome']), 
               np.where(df['AnnualIncome'] <= 51900,
                        (3215.5 + ((df['income']- 21450) * .28)),
                              (11743.5 + (df['AnnualIncome'] - 51900) * .31)
                ) 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line returns a `tuple` because of the `,`:

```py
        return (11,743.5 + ((AnnualIncome - 51900) * .31))
```

Try:

```py
        return (11743.5 + ((AnnualIncome - 51900) * .31))
```

Comment: the number `11.743.5` in my original answer is invalid as well. Is that supposed to be `11.7435` or `11743.5`? From the context I'd assume `11743.5`.

Answer (score 0):

As much as you can, avoid `DataFrame.apply` which is a hidden loop. Since your function uses logical, mutually exclusive conditions, consider [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to process assignment as whole arrays and not row wise scalar values:

```
condlist = [(0 < wages['AnnualIncome']) & (wages['AnnualIncome'] <= 21450),
            (21450 < wages['AnnualIncome']) & (wages['AnnualIncome'] <= 51900),
            (0 >= wages['AnnualIncome']) | (wages['AnnualIncome'] > 51900)]

choicelist = [(.15 * wages['AnnualIncome']),
              (3215.5 + ((wages['AnnualIncome'] - 21450) * .28)),
              (11,743.5 + ((wages['AnnualIncome'] - 51900) * .31))]

wages['Tax'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
wages['NetEarning'] = wages['AnnualIncome'] - wages['Tax']
```